# Como logro poner un archivo en el repositorio GIT que despues no sea trackeado?

Tags: git

Tengo una archivo .ini en el repostorio. Se supone que es un ini de ejemplo, uno default, que de algun modo documenta las posibles claves que existen para setear.
Quiero que la persona que se clone el repositorio lo tenga con esos defaults. Pero despues cada desarrollador va a tener su ini personal con sus opciones.
Distribuyo tambien un archivo .gitIgnore donde lo menciono explicitamente,
Sin embargo no logro que git no quiera trackearlo.
Cual seria la mejor manera de lograr esto?

Comment: Hola, que raro que git ignore no te tome el archivo que quieres que no sea stageado, pero aqui quizas haya algo que te pueda ayudar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833561/why-doesnt-git-ignore-my-specified-file/3833675

Comment: En caso de que un archivo esté ya incluido en un repositorio, Git ignorará su entrada en .gitignore hasta que éste sea borrado.